# error TS2554: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to add `{ useHash: true }` to `RouterModule.forRoot` and running into below error,is there a way to add more arguments?

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(
    appRoutes,
    { enableTracing: true } ,// <-- debugging purposes only
    { useHash: true }
  )],
  exports: [RouterModule]

})
```

ERROR:-

> ERROR in src/app/app-routing.module.ts(26,5): error TS2554: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `RouterModule.forRoot` is a configuration object, so I think what you're after is this:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(
    appRoutes,
    { enableTracing: true, useHash: true }
  )],
  exports: [RouterModule]

})
```